# find Optimal K when K may be >= 1000 (880,023 rows of data, ~200,000 features)

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, k-means, bigdata

I have 8800023 Facebook posts from around 1500 friends. I want to cluster these posts by "story/topic/specific thing they're talking about". For example, they may be clustered by name of TV Show, name of People, some word that is going viral, etc. This mean I have to pick very specific words not the general one, so this is what I do (using sklearn library in python).

```
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.001, max_features=2000000,
                             min_df=0.00001,
                             use_idf=True, tokenizer=tokenize_only,ngram_range=(1,3))
```

As you can see, I set max_df=0.001 and min_df=0.00001 to acquire the **specific thing** I've said above, and I end up getting around 200k features.

Next, I wanna use Kmean to cluster them, but I have **a problem finding the optimal K which is potentially more than 1000**, assuming that people talk about many things in those posts.

I have try Gap Statistic, pham et. al., but it was so terribly slow that I can't wait. and when I try pham with a small number like 1-8, It said 1 is the best number of cluster which is impossible.

Please help me go through this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On data like these, you have other - more severe - problems with k-means:

1. Users may be talking about more than one topic, and should belong to more than one cluster.
2. Users may be talking about nothing in particular, and should not belong to any cluster at all.
3. k-means is very sensitive to noise and initialization on such data. Run it 10 times, and you get 10 completely different results.

In particular the last one makes finding the "optimal" k impossible, because on the next run, a different k will be "optimal".

I'd rather use LDA.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain about number 3. How and why is it sensitive to noise and initialization on such data?

Comment: It minimizes variance. Squared errors make it sensitive to noise.